# Is it safe to make ssmtp SUID root?

Tags: linux, security, smtp, ssmtp

I'm using ssmtp, and I would like to *not* make my /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf world-readable, because it has my gateway password in cleartext. But if it is mode 600, then ssmtp run as an unprivileged user errors out with "ssmtp: Cannot open mailhub:25", because it cannot read the config file.

[This article](http://wiki.freebsd.org/SecureSSMTP) recommend creating a special ssmtp user and making it SUID, but before I add that kind of complexity to my deployment script, I want to ask:

Is it safe (barring security holes in ssmtp) to just make the ssmtp binary SUID root, so it can read the config file?

(I'm aware of the dangers of SUID in general -- no general answers please! My question is about ssmtp in particular, because I'm wondering if it has been written with being safe for SUID-root in mind.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Read the article again. It does not recommend running ssmtp as root**. It says to chown the file to a special ssmtp user and use SUID to run the program as that user. This isn't even close to the same as what you're proposing.

Also: *be aware you're reading a guide for [FreeBSD](http://freebsd.org); which **is not Linux***. You should not blindly assume those directions will work for a Linux system (they almost certainly will not).

Comment: +1: (a) No, do not run this as root. Bad and Wrong. ; (b) FreeBSD != Linux - Find a guide for the OS (and distribution) you're using...)

Comment: I know what the article says (I wasn't claiming that it recommends SUID root), and I did see the "FreeBSD" in the title too -- it's kinda hard to miss. ;-) I also know it's generally better practice to use an unprivileged special user account, but my question is: Has ssmtp been written so that it's safe (barring security holes) to make it SUID root (like sendmail for instance)?

Comment: No; SSMTP will not change it's own process user as some daemons will.

Comment: I see -- thanks! (I'd upvote your answer, but serverfault won't let me at this point.)